# How can I shear an image within Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, image, core-graphics, effect

I'm making a Objective-C class that can apply lots of effects on images.

I would like to implement a shear effect on an image (like you'd see in a tool within something like Adobe Illustrator), but I'm not sure how to proceed.  I already have a method within this image manipulation class that can rotate the object.  I believe that I need something similar to shear this image, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

How can I shear an image within Cocoa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read about [affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformations) and [transformation matrices](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-CJBECIAD). Shearing an image in Quartz is as simple as applying an appropriate transformation matrix.

Here's another [nice introduction to affine transformations](http://www.quantdec.com/GIS/affine.htm).